# Electron builder failed: failed to downald packages from github

Tags: electron, electron-builder

i need to run electron-builder to use electron-updat, but whenever i run the build it failed

```
• electron-builder  version=23.6.0 os=10.0.19044
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • description is missed in the package.json  appPackageFile=C:\Users\ZRGH5903.AD\Desktop\Documentation\Angular\snapface\package.json
  • writing effective config  file=newbuild\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=23.2.0 appOutDir=newbuild\win-unpacked
 ` ⨯ Get "https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v23.2.0/electron-v23.2.0-win32-x64.zip": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp :0: connectex: The requested address is not valid in its context.`
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/download.(*Downloader).follow.func1
        /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/download/downloader.go:206
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/download.(*Downloader).follow
        /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/download/downloader.go:234
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/download.(*Downloader).DownloadNoRetry
        /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/download/downloader.go:128
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/download.(*Downloader).Download
        /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/download/downloader.go:112
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/electron.(*ElectronDownloader).doDownload
        /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/electron/electronDownloader.go:192
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/electron.(*ElectronDownloader).Download
        /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/electron/electronDownloader.go:177
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/electron.downloadElectron.func1.1
        /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/electron/electronDownloader.go:73
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/util.MapAsyncConcurrency.func2
        /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/util/async.go:68
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1581  
  ⨯ C:\Users\ZRGH5903.AD\Desktop\Documentation\Angular\snapface\node_modules\app-builder-bin\win\x64\app-builder.exe process failed ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
Exit code:
1  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: C:\Users\ZRGH5903.AD\Desktop\Documentation\Angular\snapface\node_modules\app-builder-bin\win\x64\app-builder.exe process failed ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
Exit code:
1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ZRGH5903.AD\Desktop\Documentation\Angular\snapface\node_modules\builder-util\src\util.ts:250:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\ZRGH5903.AD\Desktop\Documentation\Angular\snapface\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
```

i tried many version but still same problem, can someone help me